# Automatizar lista de preguntas destacadas en la información de etiquetas

Tags: discusión, característica-nueva

En algunas etiquetas hay un apartado que se suele llamar **Preguntas destacadas** el cual al parecer es puesto a mano y a criterio de quien lo ponga (ver por ejemplo la etiqueta de <kbd>[Android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/android/info)</kbd>).

Me pregunto si existe alguna query o algún tipo de comando con el que poder presentar dicha lista de preguntas destacadas, tomando como criterio sea el número de votos, sea el número de visitas... o haciendo un cálculo algo más complejo en base a otros criterios.

De ese modo se podría tener por ejemplo las 10 preguntas más destacadas relativas a esa etiqueta, y mantener dicha lista actualizada en base a un cálculo real.

¿Qué opinan?

Comment: Lo que existe son las secciones [frecuentes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android?sort=frequent&pageSize=50) (preguntas más enlazadas) y [votos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android?sort=votes&pageSize=50) (preguntas con más votos). En general, en las wikis suelen ponerse aquellas que los activos en la etiqueta detectan como FAQ, lo que vendría a coincidir con la sección _frecuentes_.

Comment: Es punto de vista personal, no veo necesario ese apartado dentro de la información de la etiqueta. Las preguntas más destacadas serían las que se pueden acceder en los tabs que vienen en la información de la etiqueta en este caso [votos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android?sort=votes).

Comment: @fedorqui no me parece una mala idea poner un enlace a las preguntas más frecuentes y a las más votadas por ejemplo.

Comment: @A.Cedano para mí lo de las más frecuentes podría ser más útil que las más votadas, pues esto último todos sabemos que depende de mil factores y no siempre de utilidad. A mí me gusta fijarme en la [wiki de Bash en SO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info). Allí con el tiempo han ido añadiendo documentación pero también las preguntas más comunes para intentar hacer un compendio. Sirve para novatos, pero especialmente para que los usuarios frecuentes tengan más fácil encontrar canónicas a la hora de marcar duplicados.

Comment: @fedorqui ¿y sabes cómo mantienen los enlaces actualizados? hacerlo a mano y mantenerlo sería tremendo trabajo. Mi pregunta iba orientada a eso, a alguna forma de automatización en base a ciertos criterios, usando por ejemplo queries.

Comment: Los actualiza la gente, normalmente comentándolo antes a través del chat. A mí no me gusta la idea de automatizarlo porque es básicamente la información que ya aparece en _frecuentas_ y _votos_. Lo interesante es que los gurús del tema vayan mejorando la documentación y seleccionando las "perlas" con el tiempo, siguiendo la filosofía wiki.

Answer (score 3):

Yo [agregué](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/115/revisions#rev-arrow-aed99861-dab1-4f31-be2d-72bb949a36fa) esas preguntas, pero tené en cuenta que fue hace 1 año y medio, cuando no había muchas preguntas que podamos identificar como "emblemáticas" en [android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android).

Mi idea era dar pie a una lista de **preguntas canónicas**, las que se usan habitualmente para cerrar como duplicado de otras (aunque la comunidad de Android en SOes parece desconocer un poco esto de cerrar como duplicado!), algo similar al ejemplo que dio fedorqui para [Bash en SO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info).

Actualmente no se puede automatizar. En cuanto a tu planteo de que esté como característica nueva, pienso que la wiki de etiqueta no es el lugar para las más votadas (o el top N de lo que se te ocurra). Sería lo mismo que un resultado de búsqueda o alguno de los tantos filtros que ya están en el sitio, por lo que no creo que sea útil tenerlo también en un lugar tan "oculto".

Editado manualmente, puede ser un buen lugar para una especie de FAQ, para las preguntas que todo desarrollador hace habitualmente, en las que las respuestas ya pasaron por una maduración considerable y para las cuales hay una única publicación indiscutible de cómo solucionar el tema. Pero no por un cálculo o sistema de puntaje, sino por **conceptos** a mostrar y **criterio** profesional para seleccionar estos temas.

Fue un primer paso cuando el sitio era joven... hay que actualizarlo (o eliminarlo).

Comment: Plantée la pregunta pensando en algún procedimiento automático, porque me imaginaba que mantener algo del estilo supondría un enorme trabajo si lo hace uno solo... o un trabajo coordinado entre varias personas. Los comentarios de @fedorqui en la pregunta con respecto a la etiqueta `bash` en el sitio en inglés y tu respuesta confirman lo que yo pensaba. La conclusión sería entonces que un trabajo de tal calibre no se puede automatizar.

Comment: @A.Cedano exacto... te había entendido, y releyendo veo que obvié esa parte. Lo agregué ahora.